# Video call between an intercom device (SIP) and a web client (WebRTC)

Tags: webrtc, sip, voip, sip-server

I have been reading a lot of SIP/WebRTC documentation and it is not clear to me whether a video call between an intercom device (SIP) and a web client (WebRTC) can be established.

I have researched and played with various VoIP server/frameworks like OverSIP, Asterisk, Kamailio, JSSIP, PJSIP, FreeSwitch, dratchio ... and all I have got is to receive the SIP device call in the server.

The basic flow for the PoC would be as follows:

- SIP device (video door entry) initiates call to the server
- Server receive the call
- The client can contest the videocall using a web page.

The complete flow would be as follows (always the same flow):

- SIP device (video door entry) initiates call to the server
- Server determine the destination client
- Server make a temporal webpage to contest the videocall
- Server sends the URL using a notification to client's mobile device (or clients mobiles, in plural)
- The mobile receive the notification and open the web page showing the video call
- The customer can answer the video call from the web

It's possible? Is there an example or tutorial for help?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check https://sipjs.com/ ? There is documentation for multiple sip server and documentation for using the api to create web client

Comment: Yes, I check this library but I haven't been able to integrate it with my server

Comment: It can be done with the mizu webrtc-sip gateway, but that is a commercial solution.